# updatng schema after changes in entity - Symfony2 / Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I just uploaded a changed entity to my server and wanted to update my schema via `php app/console doctrine:shema:update --dump-sql`. (I need to change an smallint into an longtext (simple_array type).) This worked fine on my test server, but on my productive server, after uploading the changed entity, symfony tells me that the schema doesnt need to be updated.
What did I forget?

Comment: Have you changed the smallint into longtext in your Entity.orm.yml file ?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I have no idea which file you are talking about. The mapping of my columnin my entity looks like this  /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(name="sector", type="simple_array", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $sector = array();   as mentioned before, when I tried this on my test server, symfony recognized the changes and wanted to change the schema. I already tried clearing the cache, but that didn`t work.

Comment: the entity that you changed and uploaded is a .php file or a .orm.yml file ?

Comment: Okey, maybe that's why it tells you that the schema doesnt need to be updated, try changing in your .orm.yml file and upload it & try "php app/console doctrine:shema:update --dump-sql" to see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do in production

```
app/console doctrine:shema:update --dump-sql -e prod
```

Symfony executes all console commands in the dev env by default, so you should to specify prod

Answer (score 0):

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```